# Jinja Bootstrap modal not showing over swf file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flash, jinja2

Every time I click the modal on firefox it shows up under the swf.

I tried putting in the param to make it transparent as suggested [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4126)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" role="dialog" data-target="#save">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>
</button>
<row class="col-md-12">
        <div class="text-center embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 text-center " wmode="transparent" ><embed src="/static{{ game.game_swf }}" name="wmode" value="transparent" /></div>
</row>

<div class="modal fade" id="save" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
     <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Archive List and Start New</h3>
    </div>

   <form role="form_list" class="form form-medium" action="." method="post">

    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Save list as: </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="#">
          <button class="btn btn-success">Archive List</button></a>
    </div>
  </form>

  </div><!-- modal content -->
  </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- modal -->s
```

But for some reason it still shows the swf over the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

Changed the emebed to a object with params.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/static{{ game.game_swf }}">
 <param name="movie" value="/static{{ game.game_swf }}">
 <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

Comment: although this solves the modal overlay problem the swf does not function well. :-/